# Application not displaying a 404 Not Found Page for ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC when using identityserver 4

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using IdenitityServer 4 to hendle my users, However, when a user browses a URL that does not exist, it redirects them to the login page instead of `/not-found` page. What am I missing?

Program.cs

```
// IdentityServer4 configurations
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
}).AddCookie("cookies", c => c.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8))
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["ServiceUrls:IdentityApi"];
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.ClientId = "WebClient";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";    
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("sub", "sub", "sub");
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
    options.Scope.Add("admin");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");    
    app.UseHsts();
}

//Hnadle unhandled exceptions 500 erros
app.UseExceptionHandler("/server-error");
//Handle 404 erros
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !ctx.Response.HasStarted)
    {        
        ctx.Request.Path = "/not-found";
        await next();
    }
});
```

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("not-found")]
public IActionResult PageNotFound()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What happens if you log in and then go to the non-existent page?

Comment: Then it goes to the /files path. '/files' is one of the tabs in the menu.